# Why is this not tail recursive

Tags: recursion, f#, tail-recursion

I've got a (co?)recursive pair of functions that process a list of tuples, and fold them into batches based on some start and end criteria.

I don't do f# that much so I may be being stupid.

I've already amended a simple non tail recursive version into this, by explicitly introducing a "tot" parameter that constitutes the current folded state, what I believed to be tail recursive, yet I get the dreaded stack overflow on large inputs....(in both debugger and (debug) .exe)

There probably is a better way of doing this as an explicit fold...but that's almost not the point, the point is why is it seemingly not tail recursice?

```
    let rec ignoreUntil2 (xs : List<(string * string)>)  tot = //: List<(string * string)> -> List<List<(string * string)>> -> List<List<(string * string)>> = 
        match xs with              
        | [] -> tot
        | ((s1,s2)::tail) -> 
            if s2.StartsWith("Start importing record: Product") then
                takeUntil2 [] ((s1,s2)::tail) tot
            else
                ignoreUntil2 tail tot
and takeUntil2 acc xs tot = // : List<(string * string)> -> List<(string * string)> -> List<List<(string * string)>> -> List<List<(string * string)>> =
        match xs with
        | [] -> acc :: tot
        | ((s1,s2)::tail)   ->
            let newAcc = ((s1,s2)::acc)
            if s2.StartsWith("Finished importing record: Product") then
                ignoreUntil2 tail (newAcc :: tot)
            else
                takeUntil2 newAcc tail tot
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code *is* tail recursive.

> (in both debugger and (debug) .exe)

By default the F# compiler does not eliminate tail calls in debug mode. You'll need to either enable the `--tailcalls` option explicitly or compile in release mode.

Comment: ahchchch this is the second time in my life this has stung me.

Comment: I (lazily) always deploy code in debug (I'm a c# programmer professionally), just because it makes the errors so much nicer, and I cant be fussed with managing debug vs production builds.

Comment: let me try that

Comment: how do you enable it!?!?! you put "--tailcalls" somewhere hidden and horrid?

Comment: In Visual Studio, it can be enabled for the Debug build by going to Project -> Properties, selecting Build, and and checking the "Generate tail calls" box.

Comment: found it!...a tiny tickbox

Comment: it worked....I knew it didn't work by default in the debugger by default...I STUPIDLY thought the compiled exe would work...though that may not actually make sense.